# Biharmonic boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I try to solve

$$\Delta^2u=f$$ on unit square. with $f=4\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$

Using  $v=-\Delta u,$
leads to 
$$v+\Delta u=0,$$
$$-\Delta v=f.$$

By Dirichlet boundary condition on $u$.

What is the another boundary condition?
Could I use Dirichlet boundary condition for $v$?When I use this condition the answer is true. Otherwise it is false.

How could I determine the boundary condition.
Is there any refrence to help me about that?

Please help me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: This example is also discussed in Evans *Partial Differential Equations*.

Comment: Could you please tell me what chapter discussed about it.I did not find it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the book here, I just recall studying this example from my PDE class.

Comment: This is just a queation in that book. there is not any discuss about it.